# Which account is used by ethers.js in contractFactory.deploy()？

Tags: ether, ethers.js, hardhat

I am using hardhat to write unit test for smart contract. Before I test different functions within a contract, I have to deploy the contract first.

I read some examples, the code is like below:

```
const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners()
const tokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
const token = await tokenFactory.connect(deployer).deploy();
```

but when I try

```
const tokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
const token = await tokenFactory.deploy();
```

my test also succeeds.

My question is: which account is using when does have `.connect(deployer)` after smart contract factory. I check the document of ethers.js but without luck.

When I want to deploy with a specific address, what is the best practice to specify the address for smart contract factory in ethers.js?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In local testing with hardhat:

```
const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners()
```

returns the first account (account[0]) provided by the hardhat test accounts.
If you would then, for instance

```
 const [deployer,user1] = await ethers.getSigners()
```

you would retrieve the first ccount and the second.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi donoso, thanks for your answer. Maybe I did not post a clear question. The question is: I can use both of `const token = await tokenFactory.deploy();` and `tokenFactory.connect(deployer).deploy();` to deploy contracts, when `.connect(deployer)` is missing, what account is used?